# Timezone is set to Kolkata only

Tags: 18.04

Unlike in previous version Ubuntu 18.04 Does not have Timezone for New Delhi.It is only set to IST(Kolkata,India).

Comment: If they have same time, why does that matter? I imagine there're thousands of cities that are not included into time-zone naming.

Comment: And also perhaps false memory? As per [IANA tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) there is no entry for "New Delhi", but there is one called "Asia/Calcutta" (which licks to "Asia/Kolkata"). If I'm not mistaken Ubuntu always showed time-zones based on this database.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 also there I can choose time zone to New Delhi

Comment: Here is the list for 14.04 http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man3/DateTime::TimeZone::Catalog.3pm.html

Comment: Whole of India falls under same time zone. Hence there should be no issues.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter cause be it New Delhi or Kolkata You are in same time zone which is +5:30GMT or Indian Standard Time(IST)